# VBA Macro function out of range

Tags: excel, vba

```
Function getNames()
    Dim  wbThis As Workbook,  arr() As Variant, i As Long
    Set wbThis = ThisWorkbook
    For i = 1 To 50
        arr(i) = wbThis.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(6, i).Value
    Next i

    For i = 1 To 50
        MsgBox "employee names are***** ." + arr(i)
    Next i
End Function
```

I have above my VBA macro code in Sheet1 .In sheet1 I have one click button .on clicking the buttton,i called the getNames function. In sheet1 I have all row and column values .But when i run it shows

> subscript out of range/run time error '9'

I tried a lot.Anyone have any idea on this .

Comment: You need to supply the dimensions of your array before you reference them, I.e. redim arr(1 to 50).  Assigning the array to a range of values would work as well, but with two dimensions: arr = wbthis.sheets(“sheet1”).cells(6, 1).resize(1,50).value, then reference it as arr(1,I)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign some size to the variant array.

```
Function getNames()
    Dim wbThis As Workbook, i As Long

    Set wbThis = ThisWorkbook

    redim arr(1 to 50) As Variant

    For i = lbound(arr) To ubound(arr)
        arr(i) = wbThis.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(6, i).Value
    Next i

    For i = lbound(arr) To ubound(arr)
        MsgBox "employee names are***** ." & arr(i)
    Next i
End Function
```

`ReDim` can be used without `Dim` first. `LBound` to `UBound` is a more versatile method of looping through a static array from the lower boundary to the upper boundary. The ampersand `&` is the preferred operator for string concatenation.

Functions are intended to return a value. This may be better as a `sub` procedure.

You can 'seed' an array by calling the function from a sub.

```
sub main()

    dim i as long, nms as variant

    nms = getNames()

    For i = lbound(nms) To ubound(nms)
        MsgBox "employee names are***** ." & nms(i)
    Next i

end sub

Function getNames()
    Dim  wbThis As Workbook,  i As Long

    Set wbThis = ThisWorkbook

    redim arr(1 to 50) As Variant

    For i = lbound(arr) To ubound(arr)
        arr(i) = wbThis.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(6, i).Value
    Next i

    getnames = arr

End Function
```